# Select corresponding/multiple bars on bokeh vbar with taptool

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm currently working with data from a sports related test. I want to visualize the (multidimensional) test-data of one athlete from several tests (different dates), so I made grouped vbar with the dates at the lowest level of grouping. Now I want to tap on one bar to select it and the corresponding ones from the same date should be selected (and highlighted), too.
Till now I was searching on stackoverflow with "[python][bokeh]taptool" query, I looked up the whole issues section on git/bokeh with the tag "taptool" and did a google with similar queries, but I can't find a matching thread.

To clarify my needs, I modified the grouped_bars_example from the bokeh repository. My goal is to select all bars of one manufacturer by clicking on one bar. (I know it's possible to hold shift-key for multiselections, but it is quiet annoying to select, for example, 6 corresponding bars out of 120 bars. Thatswhy I'm looking for an efficient way to do so with one click)

```
#### basic example code from ~/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#grouped
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

# output_file('bars.html')

# preparing data for figure
df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
df.yr = df.yr.astype(str)

group = df.groupby(('cyl', 'mfr'))

source = ColumnDataSource(group)
index_cmap = factor_cmap('cyl_mfr', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(df.cyl.unique()), end=1)

# setting up figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Mean MPG by # Cylinders and Manufacturer",
           x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tools="")

# adding grouped vbar
p.vbar(x='cyl_mfr', top='mpg_mean', width=1, source=source,
       line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

# figurestyling
p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Manufacturer grouped by # Cylinders"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

# adding Tools
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("MPG", "@mpg_mean"), ("Cyl, Mfr", "@cyl_mfr")]))
p.add_tools(TapTool())


#### my additional code
import pandas as pd
import sys
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

# redirect output in files (just for debugging)
save_stderr = sys.stderr
f_err = open('error.log', 'w')
sys.stderr = f_err

save_stdout = sys.stdout
f_info = open('info.log', 'w')
sys.stdout = f_info

# callbackfunction to obtain selected bars
def callback_tap(attr, old, new):
    # write selected indices to file
    output = source.selected['1d']['indices']  # indices of selected bars
    print(output, type(output))

    # make calculations only, if one bar is selected
    if len(output) == 1:
        # find all corresponding indices to manufacturer based on selected bar
        #   get manufacturer corresponding to retrieved index
        man = source.data['cyl_mfr'][output][1]
        #   temporary DataFrame
        tmp = pd.DataFrame(source.data['cyl_mfr'].tolist(), columns=['cyl', 'mfr'])
        #   look up all corresponding indices for manufacturer "man"
        indices = tmp.index[tmp.mfr == man].values.tolist()

        # assing list of indices
        source.selected['1d']['indices'] = indices

# assigning callbackfunction
source.on_change('selected', callback_tap)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Please note, that I change the output to run a bokeh server in order to have custom python callback. For debugging reasons, I redirected the outputs to files.
In my callback function, the first part is working fine, and I retrieve the indicees of the selected bar. Additionally, I find the corresponding indicees with an DataFrame, but at the end I'm struggle to assign the new indicees in a way, that the vbar figure is updated.

I'll be very happy, if someone can help me.